# Jquery datatables server-side does not call action within a controller

Tags: c#, ajax, datatables, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm learning [jquery-datatables](https://datatables.net/) in my ASP.NET Core MVC project. The problem is that the datatables doesn't call the server-side action method.

`CrudController`

```
[HttpPost]

public object GetStudents()
{
    var test = student.GetAll(10, 0); //List<Student> the count result is 2
    return new {
        draw = 2,
        recordsTotal = 2,
        recordsFiltered = 2,
        data = test
    };
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

`HTML for IActionResult Index`

```
<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Birthdate</th>
            <th>Active</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

`Script for datatables inside $(document).ready`

```
$("#example").DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                    url: "@Url.Action("GetStudents", "Crud")",
                    type: "POST"
                },
                "columns": [
                        { "data": "id" },
                        { "data": "name" },
                        { "data": "birthdate" },
                        { "data": "active" }
                ]
        });
```

The above codes do not generate error. But `GetStudents()` method is not called (I put a breakpoint). What's wrong with them?

Comment: url: "/Crud/GetStudents"

Comment: Have you changed the url as suggested by @AsifRaza? You may have to specify the full url, not just the controller & method.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller definition is looking bit wrong to me.

It should return json data

```
 public class CrudController : Controller  
    {             
        public ActionResult Index()  
        {  
            return View();  
        }  
        public JsonResult GetStudents()  
        {  
            try  
            {  
                var result = <data list>
                return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                    
            }  
            catch (Exception ex)  
            {  
                //Log ex.Message 
            }  
        }
    }
```

Then in the client side

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#example').DataTable({  
        "ajax": {  
            "url": "/Crud/GetStudents",  
            "dataSrc": ""  
        },  
        "columns": [{  
            "data": "some col"  
        }, {  
            "data": "some other col"  
        }, 
        .... ]  
    });  
});
```

Also use network tab of chrome/fiddler to inspect the request.

Comment: The method `GetStudents` isn't called by the datatables. On the other hand, I successfully call it using `$.getJSON`. The problem is not the return value but why the datatables is unable to call this method.

Comment: Did you try the way I said?Your controller is returning a object which should return actually a json